# exeファイルの情報について

Tags: windows

exeファイルに関する質問です。
exeファイルをWindowsのプロパティで開くと、ファイルの説明や著作権情報、バージョン情報を確認できます。

私は最初、このような情報は.resに記述されていると考えましたが、.resを調べてもそのような情報は記述されていませんでした。
では、これらの情報はexeファイルのどこに保存されているのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11185104196

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VERSIONINFO resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx)に記述されています。

> 私は最初、このような情報は.resに記述されていると考えましたが、.resを調べてもそのような情報は記述されていませんでした。

.exeには複数のリソースが連結されて格納されています。参照した.res以外のリソースに記述されていたのかもしれません。